# php call array from one function to another function

Tags: php, wordpress

im writing a wordpress plugin where i've encountered a problem....
how can i call my array $start from a function named inputFraInputtable into a function named time_registrering?
below is the function i'm trying to call it to and where im calling it from

```
function time_registrering(){



inputtable_func();
inputFraInputtable(
$date,
$start,
$slut,
$pause,
$egenb,
$tot
);
print_r($start);
echo $start[startA];
}


function time_registrering(){
```

---

```
 function inputFraInputtable() {
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    global $_POST;
$date = array(
    'dateA'=>$_POST['dateA'],
    'dateB'=>$_POST['dateB'],
    'dateC'=>$_POST['dateC'],
    'dateD'=>$_POST['dateD'],
    'dateE'=>$_POST['dateE'],
    'dateF'=>$_POST['dateF'],
    'dateG'=>$_POST['dateG'],
);
    $start = array(
    'startA'=>$_POST['startA'], 
    'startB'=>$_POST['startB'], 
    'startC'=>$_POST['startC'], 
    'startD'=>$_POST['startD'], 
    'startE'=>$_POST['startE'], 
    'startF'=>$_POST['startF'],
    'startG'=>$_POST['startG'],
    );
$slut = array(
    'slutA'=>$_POST['slutA'],
    'slutB'=>$_POST['slutB'],
    'slutC'=>$_POST['slutC'],
    'slutD'=>$_POST['slutD'],
    'slutE'=>$_POST['slutE'],
    'slutF'=>$_POST['slutF'],
    'slutG'=>$_POST['slutG'],
    );
$pause = array(
    'pauseA'=>$_POST['pauseA'],
    'pauseB'=>$_POST['pauseB'],
    'pauseC'=>$_POST['pauseC'],
    'pauseD'=>$_POST['pauseD'],
    'pauseE'=>$_POST['pauseE'],
    'pauseF'=>$_POST['pauseF'],
    'pauseG'=>$_POST['pauseG'],
);
$egenb = array(
    'egenbA'=>$_POST['egenbA'],
    'egenbB'=>$_POST['egenbB'],
    'egenbC'=>$_POST['egenbC'],
    'egenbD'=>$_POST['egenbD'],
    'egenbE'=>$_POST['egenbE'],
    'egenbF'=>$_POST['egenbF'],
    'egenbG'=>$_POST['egenbG'],
);
$tot = array(
    'totA'=>$_POST['totA'],
    'totB'=>$_POST['totB'],
    'totC'=>$_POST['totC'],
    'totD'=>$_POST['totD'],
    'totE'=>$_POST['totE'],
    'totF'=>$_POST['totF'],
    'totG'=>$_POST['totG'],
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

E.g. by passing that array as an parameter of the function

```
<?php
foo();

function foo() {
    $start = array('x','y','z');

    echo '[', bar($start), ']';
}

function bar(array $items) {
    return join(', ', $items);
}
```

foo() somehow builds an array, passes it to bar(), bar() does something with it and returns something. That return value again is echo's in foo().

see:
http://docs.php.net/language.variables.scope
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection